# How to use ML or DL for predicting a value given a pattern

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, pattern-recognition

So, I have a folder named Cycles in which I have multiple (say 1000) csv files. Each of this csv file has four parameters and how they vary with time from t=0 to t=900. For more clarity, each csv file is corresponding to either a charge cycle or discharge cycle of a battery and four parameters are voltage across battery, current thru battery, etc. Now, I have one metadata csv file in which I have been given three columns, namely, 1) type of cycle(Charge or Discharge), 2) battery capacity, 3) filename of csv file in "Cycles" folder which corresponds to this reading.

In this metadata file first reading is of Charge cycle then Discharge cycle and so on. Now, after one Charge and Discharge cycle I have been given a battery impedance value.

My task is to given any new csv file similar to one in "Cycles" folder, I have to predict battery impedance. **Help me with the resources which I can refer to implement an ML model to do this.** It is important that I am predicting on how the values are changing with time, i.e. I dont have to predict given only one reading but a csv file showing a new cycle.

I am thinking that this is not a sequence problem because I am not predicting next value based on history of previous values or anything like that. *In a sense, based on how a pattern is varying it is given a value(Impedance in this case) and I want to predict a value given to such pattern.*

**Thanks for helping in advance.**

Comment: Do you know the impedance of the batteries in your folder? If so, this is just an ordinary tabular task. If you want to compress the input data more, the best place to start is to understand the physical relationship between your data and impedance. I don’t know anything about that but this is a physical system.

Comment: @Sycorax Not sure if this is tabular task.

Here, the impedance depends on two things, 1)How fast battery charges given in "Cycles" folder. 2) Battery's State of Health, given as battery capacity in metadata csv file. Now, answering your first question, after one Charge or Discharge cycle, I am given the battery's impedance. Generally, as we use a battery, it deteriorates and its impedance changes, and so does the battery charging and discharging pattern(w.r.t time). So the task I want to achieve is, given a battery's specification and a charging/discharging pattern estimate it's impedance.